# Cython - Indexing numpy array within nogil function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

I'm trying to extend the `Splitter` class in sklearn, which works with sklearn's decision tree classes.  More specifically, I want to add a `feature_weights` variable in the new class, which will affect the determination of the best split point by altering the purity calculations proportionally with the feature weights.

The new class is almost an exact copy of sklearn's `BestSplitter` class (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx) with only minor changes.  Here's what I have so far:

```
cdef class WeightedBestSplitter(WeightedBaseDenseSplitter):

    cdef object feature_weights # new variable - 1D array of feature weights

    def __reduce__(self):
        # same as sklearn BestSplitter (basically)

    # NEW METHOD
    def set_weights(self, object feature_weights): 
        feature_weights = np.asfortranarray(feature_weights, dtype=DTYPE)
        self.feature_weights = feature_weights  

    cdef int node_split(self, double impurity, SplitRecord* split,
                        SIZE_t* n_constant_features) nogil except -1:

        # .... same as sklearn BestSplitter ....

        current_proxy_improvement = self.criterion.proxy_impurity_improvement()
        current_proxy_improvement *= self.feature_weights[<int>(current.feature)]  # new line

        # .... same as sklearn BestSplitter ....
```

A couple notes about the above: I'm using the `object` variable type and `np.asfortranarray` because that is how the variable `X` is defined and set in other places and `X` is indexed like I'm trying to index `feature_weights`.  Also, `custom.feature` has a variable type of `SIZE_t` per the `_splitter.pxd` file (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pxd).

The issue seems to be created by the variable type of `self.feature_weights`.  The above code throws multiple errors, but even trying to reference something like `self.feature_weights[0]` and set it to another variable throws the error:

```
Indexing Python object not allowed without gil
```

I'm wondering what I need to do to be able to index `self.feature_weights` and use the scalar value as a multiplier.

Comment: Searching on `cython` and `nogil`, produces (among other things): https://lbolla.info/python-threads-cython-gil, "Cython offers a wonderful context manager to run instructions without the GIL: with nogil. The catch is that it can only be used to run code that does not touch any Python object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can't index a generic Python object without the GIL (as you're trying to do). You can index typed memoyviews without the GIL.

Define `feature_weights` as

```
cdef double[:] feature_weights
```

Comment: This does the trick.  I'm not used to casting in that way, if that's even the right term.  Any idea why `self.X` can be of type `object` and still be indexed?  I traced it back to `X = np.asfortranarray(X, dtype=DTYPE)` within the `TreeBuilder` class (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx), similar to the way I have it above.

Comment: It's just a Numpy array. It defines `__getitem__` so it can be indexed in Python. Defining as a typed memoryview gives Cython a direct way of accessing the data so the indexing works faster and doesn't need the GIL.